# get back the value of varibles created on php url

Tags: php, ajax

I want to get back and use on my index.php the value of commentNewCount which will be created on load-comments.php. How can I do that?

```
 <script>   
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var commentCount = 2;
        $("button").click(function() {
            commentCount = commentCount + 2;
            $("#comments").load("load-comments.php", {
                commentNewCount: commentCount
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

load-comments.php

```
    <?php
    include 'dbh.php';

    $commentNewCount = $_POST['commentNewCount'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT $commentNewCount";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<p>";
            echo $row['author'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row['message'];
            echo "</p>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "There are no comments!";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to pass variable from one page to another then you can either save the value of commentNewCount to a SESSION variable or COOKIE.

```
//on load-comments.php
$_SESSION['commentCount'] = $_POST['commentNewCount'];

//on index.php
$commentCount = $_SESSION['commentCount'];
```